# Internet sharing on Mac cuts out ethernet connection to Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, static-ip

I have my Raspberry Pi connected to my Mac via ethernet, I can ssh into it fine. But when I turn internet sharing on, the connection is cut and I can no longer ping the Raspberry Pi's IP. I've tried restarting the ethernet connection but I still get nothing.

- My raspberry Pi (running Raspbian) has the IP address: **169.254.0.2**
- DHCP sets my Mac's IP address: **169.254.3.74** With subnet: **255.255.0.0**
- The IP address on my wifi connection is: **192.168.0.4**

Can anyone enlighten me as to what's going on here?

Thanks in advance,

Ryan

Comment: Q1: The raspberry Pi IP address, is it set by DHCP or do you assign it manually? Q2: Is it correct to presume these are the IP addresses after you have turned on Internet sharing?

Comment: Yes, DHCP sets the IP addresses. I've tried setting it manually also though. And yes they are.

Comment: I don't believe that there is a DHCP server on your ethernet subnet because `169.254.0.0/16` are [self assigned ip addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address#IPv4). If they are really come from a DHCP server then there is a missconfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

The following way works for me:
First I connected my mac to the Internet via wifi
Then on system preferences> Network> Ethernet :
 Manually assigned an IP Addr, Mine is : 192.168.2.1, Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0, DNS: any free DNS servers like : 8.8.8.8 and router should be remained blank
Then on system preferences> Sharing , I marked Internet sharing, chose "share your connection from" as "WiFi" and "Ports" on "Ethernet"
Now plug your ethernet cable to the raspberry pi, and configure its connection like:
IP Addr: 192.168.2.2 (the same range address of the ethernet port of your mac)
subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Router: 192.168.2.1
DNS: 8.8.8.8

Then reboot your raspberry. Now it should be connected to the Internet